# Making entire list item clickable in HTML5

Tags: css, html

Im creating a mobile app with HTML5, backbone.js, phonegap and topcoat.io. I want to make entire list items clickable. At the moment I have:

```
<ul class="topcoat-list">


    <li class="topcoat-list__item">

        <a href="#teams">Teams</a>
    </li>

    <li class="topcoat-list__item">

        <a href="#games/1">Upcoming Fixtures</a>

    </li>

</ul>
```

But the user needs to touch "Teams" rather than anywhere on the list item. To make the whole list item clickable, I wrap it in anchor tags:

```
    <a href="#teams">
        <li class="topcoat-list__item">

            Teams
        </li>
    </a>

    <a href="#games/1">
        <li class="topcoat-list__item">

        Upcoming Fixtures
        </li>
    </a>
```

Is this the right approach? It works, but it seems dirty...

Comment: That's not valid HTML. The only children of UL are LI. Show some CSS or a demo. You should be able to get your links to fill the entire LI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Display the anchor as a block.

```
ul,li {
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
a {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Also, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/ywBPC/).

You can add a height/ width or padding to make the links bigger.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="topcoat-list__item">
    <a href="#teams">Teams</a>
</li>
<li class="topcoat-list__item">
     <a href="#games/1">Upcoming Fixtures</a>
</li>
```

Or use JS .click() function

Answer (score 0):

Although that is not valid HTML, displaying the anchors as blocks should do the trick.

```
a#teams{display:block}
```